# How to unify two SQL queries (One with common information, one with unique information)

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have two tables. A table with some common ids and common information about them. Then I have a table, which shows all the unique ids corresponding with common_ids and some unique information. I made a picture with Table1 and Table2.

I want to build a query which outputs all the common_ids and for each of them, two corresponding unique_ids. How can I do that?

My current approach is to just query all the common_ids I need, and then for each result query the id1, and then query id2. But then I have many SQL queries. I cannot figure out how to make everything in one single query.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
select common_id, min(id) as id1, max(id) as id2
from table2
group by common_id;
```